# Entity Framework - Update entity but not child entity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In my EF 6 MVC app, I have an entity Seller which has a 1:1 relationship to SellerShippingPolicies. When I update the seller entity, EF is also attempting to update the SellerShippingPolicies entity, and I don't want this to happen.

I have the following method that updates a Seller entity:

```
    public Entities.Seller Save(Entities.Seller seller)
    {
        // Instantiate a helper method
        HelperMethods helper = new HelperMethods(this.UnitOfWork);

        // Map the domain entity to an EF entity
        var sellerRecord = Mapper.Map<Seller>(seller);

        // Attempt to prevent the updating of the SellerShippingPolicies entity
        helper.GetDbContext().Entry(sellerRecord.SellerShippingPolicies).State = EntityState.Detached;

        // Save the entity
        sellerRecord = helper.SaveItem<Seller>(sellerRecord);
    }
```

Here is the SaveItem method that gets called:

```
    public T SaveItem(T entity)
    {
        var row = this._dbSet.Find(GetPrimaryKeyValue(entity));
        if ( row == null )
            return AddItem(entity);
        else
            return UpdateItem(entity);
    }
```

And the Update method that eventually gets called:

```
    public T UpdateItem(T entity)
    {
        // Retrieve the current copy of the entity to be updated.
        var currentEntity = GetItem(GetPrimaryKeyValue(entity));

        // Copy the contents of the modified entity on top of the copy we just retrieved. This way EF will save everything correctly.
        currentEntity = Copy.ShallowCopy<T>(entity, currentEntity);

        this._dbContext.SaveChanges();

        return currentEntity;
    }
```

Not sure it's necessary, but here is the method for ShallowCopy and GetItem.

```
    public static T ShallowCopy<T>(object source, T target)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            var property = source.GetType().GetProperty(pi.Name);

            if (property == null)
                continue;

            if (property.GetSetMethod() != null)
                property.SetValue(target, pi.GetValue(source, null), null);
        }
        return target;
    }

    public T GetItem(object primaryKeyValue)
    {
        return this._dbSet.Find(primaryKeyValue);
    }
```

All these methods share the same context object.

You can see that I'm attempting to prevent the updating of the SellerShippingPolicies entity by setting its state to detached. This does not work. I've also tried setting the state to Unchanged. That doesn't work either. In both cases, EF attempts to update the SellerShippingPolicies entity. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you keeping that Context from GetDbContext open? And could you show the code in SaveItem?

Comment: @RobTillie - The context only lives for the life of the method. This is a disconnected app, so contexts are spun up and down quickly.

Comment: Usually when I have the same problem, I'm using 2 different contexts. Are you sure you're setting the state in te same context as you're saving the SellerRecord?

Comment: @RobTillie - Yes it's the same context. The helper variable obtains the context and that is used.

Comment: Can you post your "HelperMethods" SaveItem method. And also your "GetDbContext" method might also be useful

Comment: Can you make `sellerRecord.SellerShippingPolicies = null;` before calling your `SaveItem`? I believe if it's `null` it will not try and do the update to the item...

Comment: I'm having to make a few assumptions because there's a few methods/functions that I cant see and I dont want to keep asking you for them piecemeal. But the SellerShippingPolicies you mark as Unchanged should never make it into the model anyway because you dont reattach the seller record. How do you know its trying to save the SellerShippingPolicies?

Comment: @MattWhetton - You're correct the SellerShippingPolicies entity isn't making it to the model, which is what's causing the error. EF is trying to update the SellerShippingPolicies entity, by inserting NULL values into columns that cannot be NULL, and errors are getting generated.

Comment: Sorry to ask for more methods - what does your ShallowCopy and GetItem methods look like?

Comment: One problem could be in your ShallowCopy method as it will copy over entire child objects. Adding the following line after your "if(property == null) continue;" step will only copy over simple property types: 

if (!property.PropertyType.IsValueType && !property.PropertyType.Equals(typeof (string)) && !property.PropertyType.Equals(typeof (byte[]))) continue;

Comment: @MattWhetton - I don't think this is it. When I save a Seller entity, the Seller EF object has a completely empty copy of SellerShippingPolicies. My problem/question is, why is EF even attempting to save this entity?

Comment: Its probably trying to update because of the way the 2 entities are related at a database level. How is the SellerShippingPolicies joined to SellerRecord? You could try something like marking the foreign key field as not modified (like this helper.GetDbContext().Entry(sellerRecord).Property("SellerShippingPolicies").IsModified = false;) -

Comment: Have you tried `State = EntityState.Unchanged`?

Comment: @RandyMinder I would try the suggestion of Matt. I suspect EF is going to try to add the empty object to the database. It should be null.